# How to export a struct's field from C

Tags: c, gcc, struct, export, symbols

If I have two C structures like this:

```
struct buffer_t {
    void *buffer;
    int length;
};

struct type_t {
    int a;
    struct buffer_t buf;
    double c;
} obj;
```

and I want to export `obj`'s second field, `buf`, so that a can reference it from another file with, for example, `extern struct buffer_t buffer` (or whatever), is there any way to achieve that? I need to export the `obj.buf` structure, not a pointer to it.

**EDIT**
I need to export specifically `obj.buf`, not the whole `obj` structure.

**EDIT2**
I think I'd better explain what I need by using assembly code. The compiler is supposed to generate the following assembly code for `obj`'s declaration:

```
    .data
    .align  8
.obj:
    .long   0            # obj.a
    .zero   8            # obj.buf.buffer
    .zero   4            # obj.buf.length
    .quad   0            # double 2
    .size   obj, 32
```

But I want to force it to produce something like:

```
    .globl  obj_buf

    .data
    .align  8
.obj:
    .long   0            # obj.a
obj_buf:
    .zero   8            # obj.buf.buffer
    .zero   4            # obj.buf.length
    .quad   0            # double 2
    .size   obj, 32
```

so that `obj.buf` is identified by a symbol. So, is there any way to make the C compiler (GCC or Clang) assign `obj.buf` a symbol?

Comment: You can put the structure definition in your interface -- letting others create that same structure? I don't think you understand what a structure is.

Comment: @JacobPollack Yes, the structure definition is public, so that anyone can create `type_t` and `buffer_t` structures. In my program I have dozens of `type_t` structures, but the `obj` one is special and I need to export its `buf` field.

Comment: @JacobPollack And, by the way, those `type_t` structures are global, of course.

Comment: Why can't you use a pointer to the buffer and just dereference it on use?

Comment: @alk Well, exporting a pointer to `obj.buf` would be the easiest way. But, unfortunately, `obj.buf` is imported from another library as a `struct buffer_t` variable, not as `struct buffer_t *` one.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Does this "other lib" do write to `buffer`?

Comment: @alk Yes, it possibly does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you can't. But if you *really really* need to get it working... this work at least with mine gcc

```
asm (".set obj_buf, obj+4\n\t.globl obj_buf\n");
```

the +4 is obviously the offset of the member in the struct, if you need to set it dinamically (eg with *offsetof*) ... you'll open another hell's door, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "export" a single structure member field.

You can however have a function that returns that specific field (or a pointer to it).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "export" a field. You can put the structure definition in your interface (header file), allowing others to create structures of that type.

To access that individual field then you would need to use pointers -- there is no other way around that. If you are not using pointers then you are mutating values on the stack and nothing happens once the stack frame is popped from the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

header.h

```
...
struct buffer_t {
  void *buffer;
  int length;
};
extern struct buffer_t * pbuffer;
...
```

module.c

```
...
#include "header.h"

struct type_t {
  int a;
  struct buffer_t buf;
  double c;
} obj;

struct buffer_t * pbuffer = &obj.buf;
...
```

anothermodule.c

```
...
#include "header.h"

void somefunction()
{
  /* access buffer to do something with it */

  printf("external buffer's length is: %d\n", (*pbuffer).length);
}
...
```

Comment: Yes, this would be the easiest and most common way to do what I need, but I need to conform to another preexisting library and it references `buf` directly as a `struct buffer_t` variable, not as a pointer and not with functions.

Comment: @LuisAntonioBotelhoO.Leite: Ok, then you need to change the other side. That is `struct type_t` to access a global external variable of type `buffer_t` via a pointer.